# Can't assign value from xml array to other variable in javascript node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, node.js

I loading data from xml and i'm trying to assign value from xml array to other value. When i put breakpoint inside then it seems that the new variable is assigned. But at view shows the old value. Check comments below.

Here is my code with comments:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sales = require('../data-access');
var fs = require('fs');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

router.get('/', function (req, res)
{
    sales.getSalesData(function (err, salesRows)
    {
        //function for loading xml
        function loadXml()
        {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
            {
                fs.readFile('data-xml/test_data.xml', function (err, data)
                {
                    if (err) return reject(err);
                    parseString(data, function (err, result)
                    {
                        if (err) return reject(err);
                        resolve(result.xml.record);
                    });
                });
            });
        }

        loadXml().then(function (globalDataxml)
        {
            // for each element i set new value from xml
            salesRows.forEach(function (saledItem) {
                saledItem.product = globalDataxml[0].product[0];
            // when i put breakpoint here it looks like that everything is fine, value changed
            });
        }).catch(function (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        });

        res.render('reports', {
            salesData: salesRows
            // but here salesRows is with old value, didn't change
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Since you already use promises I would expect you to know how they work. Well the thing is your code is actually called in following order: loadXml() -> res.render(...) -> .then(function(globalDataxml){...} Solution is simple call res.render from within then( ... )

Comment: It's not actually the *then* function that's called after res.render but rather the function callback which is put in queue and called when the promise is resolved.

Comment: Ohh, you're right. Thank you!